# [UWP][InkCanvas] How to draw a path using InkCanvas in Touch

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, inkcanvas

I am having an InkCanvas inside the Grid control and I am trying to set the **InkPresenter’s** **InputDeviceTypes** property value as **Touch** or **Mouse** in the Grid **PointerEntered** event and I changed the InkPresenter’s InputDeviceTypes to **None** in the InkPresenter **StrokeCollected** event.

So, I can enable the drawing on a pointer to enter and disable the drawing after collected the strokes. This is my requirement.

It is working properly on using the mouse, but it is not working on Touch.  I can draw the path in touch in the first time only. The second time it is not drawing.

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Code snippet:

Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerMoved="Grid_PointerMoved" 
          PointerPressed="Grid_PointerPressed">
        <Image Source="Buldingimage1.jpeg"/>
        <InkCanvas x:Name="canvas"/>
    </Grid>
```

Events

```
   private void InkPresenter_StrokesCollected(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)
    {
        canvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.None;
    }


    private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        canvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes =
       Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse |
       Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen | Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;
    }
```

Sample: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wT9MvnJyXWR91ifUV3tJZJIaNluhfyK_

Thanks,
Santhiya A

Comment: What device you have tested, I tested your code sample with Simulator touch model, it works well, I could not reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have tested in the windows machine. VS 2017 version 15.9.11.

Comment: What's your operation system version.

Comment: OS Build version : 17763.864

Comment: I test within 18363, could you try to update your system to latest version?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in the 18363 version too. Can you tell me if possible to cancel the touch interactions in PointerEntered event? ( If I touch for the first time the touch interactions will be stopped)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203756/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-santhiya).